# How to iterate over a list of list using 'in' operator

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of lists (`path_list`; actually this is a path object) and another list (`y_path`).

Now, I want to `remove` and `filter` those two lists based on another list `remove_all_list`.

The remove function (`not in`) is working fine. But, when I am using the `in` function I am getting an empty list.

Code is given below

```
remove_all_list = ["Image_034_S_0735_Img_Na__Ma_F_", "Image_033_S_0733_Img_Na__Ma_F_"]

X_test = path_list.copy()
y_test = y_path.copy()

for remove_item in remove_all_list:
    path_list = [[item for item in sub_list if remove_item not in item.name] for sub_list in path_list]
    y_path = [item for item in y_path if remove_item not in item.name]
    X_test = [[item for item in sub_list if remove_item in item.name] for sub_list in X_test]
    y_test = [item for item in y_test if remove_item in item.name]

X_train_val = [x for x in path_list if x] # Removing empty list
X_test_all = [x for x in X_test if x] # Removing empty list
```

The shape I am getting from the loop

```
print(np.shape(y_path), np.shape(X_train_val), np.shape(y_test), np.shape(X_test_all))

(2,) (2, 2) (0,) (0,)
```

But, the expected shape is `(2,) (2, 2) (2,) (2, 2)`. Any ideas are appreciated.

Reproducible data

```
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
path_list = [
    [Path('/home/0_knowle/Desktop/project/data/train/Image/Folder_1/Image_033_S_0724_Img_Na__Ma_F_.png'),
    Path('/home/0_knowle/Desktop/project/data/train/Image/Folder_2/Image_033_S_0724_Img_Na__Ma_F_.png')],

    [Path('/home/0_knowle/Desktop/project/data/train/Image/Folder_1/Image_033_S_0733_Img_Na__Ma_F_.png'),
    Path('/home/0_knowle/Desktop/project/data/train/Image/Folder_2/Image_033_S_0733_Img_Na__Ma_F_.png')],

    [Path('/home/0_knowle/Desktop/project/data/train/Image/Folder_1/Image_034_S_0734_Img_Na__Ma_F_.png'),
    Path('/home/0_knowle/Desktop/project/data/train/Image/Folder_2/Image_034_S_0734_Img_Na__Ma_F_.png')],

    [Path('/home/0_knowle/Desktop/project/data/train/Image/Folder_1/Image_034_S_0735_Img_Na__Ma_F_.png'),
    Path('/home/0_knowle/Desktop/project/data/train/Image/Folder_2/Image_034_S_0735_Img_Na__Ma_F_.png')]
  ]
y_path = [
    Path('/home/0_knowle/Desktop/project/data/train/Image/Folder_1/Image_033_S_0724_Img_Na__Ma_F_.png'),
    Path('/home/0_knowle/Desktop/project/data/train/Image/Folder_1/Image_033_S_0733_Img_Na__Ma_F_.png'),
    Path('/home/0_knowle/Desktop/project/data/train/Image/Folder_1/Image_034_S_0734_Img_Na__Ma_F_.png'),
    Path('/home/0_knowle/Desktop/project/data/train/Image/Folder_1/Image_034_S_0735_Img_Na__Ma_F_.png'),
  ]
```

Comment: Your first assignment creates a new `path_list` that does not have the matching strings.  There's nothing left to store into `X_test` and `y_test` .  Perhaps you should do it last?

Comment: Would you mind explaining a little more? As, I have `path_list` and later I am copying this to `X_test`. Then why, they don't have the matching string?

Comment: If I use `remove_all_list[0]` instead of `remove_item` of the `loop`, then also I am getting one element in the list.

Comment: Step through your code. In the first iteration, the first three elements of `X_test` are removed. In the second iteration, the last element of `X_test` is removed.

Comment: The first time through your loop, you want `X_test` to pull all of the "034_S_0735" lines from `path_list`.  But those lines are no longer IN `path_list`, because you deleted them in the very first line of your loop.

Comment: Thank you. Does it mean they are referencing the same list? Then if I use `X_test=list(path_list)` then also getting the same output. How, should I copy the list?

Comment: Sorry, I misdiagnosed your problem.  The problem is simpler than that.  The first time through your list, you keep in `X_test` ONLY the paths that contain "034_S_0735".  Thus, the second time through the loop, there are NO paths that contain "033_S_0733".  If you're trying divide `path_list` into two sets, one that matches and one that doesn't, you'll need to do it differently.  I'll post a sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this accomplished what you want.  It's more sensible to filter through the pathlist as the outer loop, then decide line by line whether it's a winner or a loser, sorting into two piles:

```
from pprint import pprint
from pathlib import Path

path_list = [
    [Path('/home/0_knowle/Desktop/project/data/train/Image/Folder_1/Image_033_S_0724_Img_Na__Ma_F_.png'),
    Path('/home/0_knowle/Desktop/project/data/train/Image/Folder_2/Image_033_S_0724_Img_Na__Ma_F_.png')],

    [Path('/home/0_knowle/Desktop/project/data/train/Image/Folder_1/Image_033_S_0733_Img_Na__Ma_F_.png'),
    Path('/home/0_knowle/Desktop/project/data/train/Image/Folder_2/Image_033_S_0733_Img_Na__Ma_F_.png')],

    [Path('/home/0_knowle/Desktop/project/data/train/Image/Folder_1/Image_034_S_0734_Img_Na__Ma_F_.png'),
    Path('/home/0_knowle/Desktop/project/data/train/Image/Folder_2/Image_034_S_0734_Img_Na__Ma_F_.png')],

    [Path('/home/0_knowle/Desktop/project/data/train/Image/Folder_1/Image_034_S_0735_Img_Na__Ma_F_.png'),
    Path('/home/0_knowle/Desktop/project/data/train/Image/Folder_2/Image_034_S_0735_Img_Na__Ma_F_.png')]
  ]
y_path = [
    Path('/home/0_knowle/Desktop/project/data/train/Image/Folder_1/Image_033_S_0724_Img_Na__Ma_F_.png'),
    Path('/home/0_knowle/Desktop/project/data/train/Image/Folder_1/Image_033_S_0733_Img_Na__Ma_F_.png'),
    Path('/home/0_knowle/Desktop/project/data/train/Image/Folder_1/Image_034_S_0734_Img_Na__Ma_F_.png'),
    Path('/home/0_knowle/Desktop/project/data/train/Image/Folder_1/Image_034_S_0735_Img_Na__Ma_F_.png'),
  ]

remove_all_list = ["Image_034_S_0735_Img_Na__Ma_F_", "Image_033_S_0733_Img_Na__Ma_F_"]

X_keep = []
X_test = []
for sub_list in path_list:
    if any(all(remove in item.name for item in sub_list) for remove in remove_all_list):
        X_test.append( sub_list )
    else:
        X_keep.append( sub_list )

y_keep = []
y_test = []
for item in y_path:
    if any(remove in item.name for remove in remove_all_list):
        y_test.append( item )
    else:
        y_keep.append( item )

print("PL")
pprint(X_keep)
print("X")
pprint(X_test)
print("yk")
pprint(y_keep)
print("y")
pprint(y_test)
```

Output:

```
PL
[[WindowsPath('/home/0_knowle/Desktop/project/data/train/Image/Folder_1/Image_033_S_0724_Img_Na__Ma_F_.png'),
  WindowsPath('/home/0_knowle/Desktop/project/data/train/Image/Folder_2/Image_033_S_0724_Img_Na__Ma_F_.png')],
 [WindowsPath('/home/0_knowle/Desktop/project/data/train/Image/Folder_1/Image_034_S_0734_Img_Na__Ma_F_.png'),
  WindowsPath('/home/0_knowle/Desktop/project/data/train/Image/Folder_2/Image_034_S_0734_Img_Na__Ma_F_.png')]]
X
[[WindowsPath('/home/0_knowle/Desktop/project/data/train/Image/Folder_1/Image_033_S_0733_Img_Na__Ma_F_.png'),
  WindowsPath('/home/0_knowle/Desktop/project/data/train/Image/Folder_2/Image_033_S_0733_Img_Na__Ma_F_.png')],
 [WindowsPath('/home/0_knowle/Desktop/project/data/train/Image/Folder_1/Image_034_S_0735_Img_Na__Ma_F_.png'),
  WindowsPath('/home/0_knowle/Desktop/project/data/train/Image/Folder_2/Image_034_S_0735_Img_Na__Ma_F_.png')]]
yk
[WindowsPath('/home/0_knowle/Desktop/project/data/train/Image/Folder_1/Image_033_S_0724_Img_Na__Ma_F_.png'),
 WindowsPath('/home/0_knowle/Desktop/project/data/train/Image/Folder_1/Image_034_S_0734_Img_Na__Ma_F_.png')]
y
[WindowsPath('/home/0_knowle/Desktop/project/data/train/Image/Folder_1/Image_033_S_0733_Img_Na__Ma_F_.png'),
 WindowsPath('/home/0_knowle/Desktop/project/data/train/Image/Folder_1/Image_034_S_0735_Img_Na__Ma_F_.png')]
```